# Adic Scalar 100 (Dell Powervault 136T) drive firmware downgrade problem

Tags: tape, firmware, downgrade

I've got an Adic Scalar 100 (also commonly rebranded by dell as powervault 136T). recently one drive failed and we put in a spare LTO2 drive into the changer.

Unfortunately, the drive has slightly newer firmware which causes the changer to complain. anyone know how to get and downgrade the firmware on this tape drive?

Comment: Since this appears in google search results now, I should also provide a link to other firmware:

http://www.quantum.com/ServiceandSupport/SoftwareandDocumentationDownloads/S100/Index.aspx

Comment: also found firmware for my particular drive:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=ssg1S1002364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will downgrade the drive firmware, but I've overcome similar problems in the past (on a PV132T) by updating the firmware on the Library itself. The Library firmware also contains drive firmware if I remember correctly, so at the very least if it won't downgrade the drive, the Library may have support for the later drive firmware.

You can download the latest firmware direct from Dell [here](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/format.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=gen&deviceid=1203&libid=37&releaseid=R143571&vercnt=1&formatcnt=0&SystemID=PWE_1950&servicetag=&os=WNET&osl=en&catid=-1&impid=-1).